# How do I use the 32-bit client?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm getting stutter/framerate issues with Patch 2.4.3. [I read online](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/20752640254#post-5) that this is likely due to issues in the (new?) 64-bit client, and that I should revert to the 32-bit client or remove myself from communities (shift+O in-game) as a short-term solution. But how do I use the 32-bit Diablo client?

Comment: I think I had same issue, where my ingame FPS (to show it use CTR+R) was low disregards of video settings (my system is capable to run modern games on maximum settings). One symptom of it is that ALT-TAB will show `MessageBox` behind the game running in full screen mode. Don't remember the message itself, "unable to acquire something"... Simply setting maxed desktop (or how is it called) mode **instead** of full screen resolve my problem. I do not recommend switching to 32 bit client if you can make 64 bit one working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Blizzard launcher, click the Battle.net icon in the upper-left corner and access the "Settings". Go to "Game Settings" (see image below) and check "Launch 32-bit client". This resolved the screen stutter issues for me.

[image: Cropped screenshot showing Game Settings tab]

Comment: Had the same issue and the same solution.

Comment: Use this also to reduce the system requirements from 4GB to 2GB